# Arcpy - Save NA layer to feature class

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm in the process of updating some old tools and models from 9.3 to 10.3 and have run into an issue trying to save an in specific layers from a Network Analysis Layer.

Below is copy of my script and the error that it is generating:

```
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\aaa\response profile\test.gdb"

inNetworkDataset = "J:\\projects\\netmodels\\roadnetwork\\Vic_HERE_2014_Q2\\Data\\HERE_COREMAP.gdb\\RoutingApplication\\RoutingApplication_ND"
outNALayerName = "StationOfInterest"
allFacilities = r"C:\aaa\response profile\RMN.gdb\RNM_Statewide_Fire_Stations"
facilitiesQuery = "not occ_type = 'future fire station' and label in ('Springvale')"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(allFacilities,"inFacilities", facilitiesQuery)
outLayerFile = r"C:\aaa\response profile" + "\\" + outNALayerName + ".lyr"
timeBreaks = 30
print "varibles set"

SA_result_object  = arcpy.na.MakeServiceAreaLayer(inNetworkDataset, outNALayerName,
                                  "EmergencyServicesTime", "TRAVEL_FROM", timeBreaks,
                                  "NO_POLYS", "NO_MERGE", "RINGS", "TRUE_LINES")
print "Service Area layer created"

#Get the layer object from the result object. The service layer can now be
#referenced using the layer object.
SA_layer_object = SA_result_object.getOutput(0)

#Get the names of all the sublayers within the service area layer.
SAClassesIn = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(SA_layer_object,"INPUT")
SAClassesOut = arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(SA_layer_object,"OUTPUT")
#Stores the layer names to use later
facilitiesLayerName = SAClassesIn["Facilities"]
print "facilitiesLayerName: " + facilitiesLayerName
linesLayerName = SAClassesOut["SALines"]
print "linesLayerName: " + linesLayerName

arcpy.na.AddLocations(SA_layer_object , SAClassesIn["Facilities"], "inFacilities")
print "added locations to layer"
print "solving...."
arcpy.na.Solve(SA_layer_object )
print"solved"

********** these are the lines that is causing me issues **********
linesSublayer = SA_layer_object.listLayers(SAClassesOut["Lines"])[0]
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(linesSublayer,"StationOfInterestLines")
```

The error I get is:

```
linesSublayer = SA_layer_object.listLayers(SAClassesOut["Lines"])[0]
AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute 'listLayers'
```

Any ideas what is causing it, I'm doing my head in trying to work it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read over the ListLayers documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listlayers.htm) -- it calls an MXD as a parameter, and isn't used as an attribute of a Layer object.

The syntax:

```
ListLayers (map_document_or_layer, {wildcard}, {data_frame})
```

So you probably want something along the lines of:

```
linesSublayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(SA_layer_object, "Lines")[0]
```